# handling DATETIME values 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in JDBC

Tags: java, sql, date, jdbc

I get an exception (see below) if I try to do

```
resultset.getString("add_date");
```

for a JDBC connection to a MySQL database containing a DATETIME value of 0000-00-00 00:00:00 (the quasi-null value for DATETIME), even though I'm just trying to get the value as string, not as an object.

I got around this by doing

```
SELECT CAST(add_date AS CHAR) as add_date
```

which works, but seems silly... is there a better way to do this?

My point is that I just want the raw DATETIME string, so I can parse it myself **as is**.

**note:** here's where the 0000 comes in: (from http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/datetime.html)

> Illegal DATETIME, DATE, or TIMESTAMP
>   values are converted to the “zero”
>   value of the appropriate type
>   ('0000-00-00 00:00:00' or
>   '0000-00-00').

The specific exception is this one:

```
SQLException: Cannot convert value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 5 to TIMESTAMP.
SQLState: S1009
VendorError: 0
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 5 to TIMESTAMP.
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:926)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getTimestampFromString(ResultSetImpl.java:6343)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5670)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5491)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5531)
```

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I stumbled across this attempting to solve the same issue.  The installation I am working with uses JBOSS and Hibernate, so I had to do this a different way.  For the basic case, you should be able to add `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull` to your connection URI as per this [configuration properties page](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html).

I found other suggestions across the land referring to putting that parameter in your hibernate config:

In *hibernate.cfg.xml*:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</property>
```

In *hibernate.properties*:

```
hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

But I had to put it in my *mysql-ds.xml* file for JBOSS as:

```
<connection-property name="zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</connection-property>
```

Hope this helps someone. :)

Comment: Doing the change on the _hibernate.cfg.xml_ file do the trick for me, thank you, because I have almost zero knowledge on Java

Answer (score 127):

Alternative answer, you can use this JDBC URL directly in your datasource configuration:

```
jdbc:mysql://yourserver:3306/yourdatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

Edit:

#### Source: [MySQL Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-installing-upgrading-3-0-to-3-1.html)

> Datetimes with all-zero components (0000-00-00 ...) — These values can not be represented  reliably in Java. Connector/J 3.0.x always converted them to NULL when being read from a  ResultSet.
>
> Connector/J 3.1 throws an exception by default when these values are encountered as this is the most correct behavior according to the JDBC and SQL standards. This behavior can be modified using the zeroDateTimeBehavior configuration property. The allowable values are:
>
> - **exception** (the default), which throws an SQLException with an SQLState of S1009.
> - **convertToNull**, which returns NULL instead of the date.
> - **round**, which rounds the date to the nearest closest value which is 0001-01-01.

Update: Alexander reported a bug affecting mysql-connector-5.1.15 on that feature. See [CHANGELOGS on the official website](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/relnotes/connector-j/5.1/en/news-5-1.html).

Comment: interesting. where'd you find this info?

Comment: just updated my answer! But @sarumont 's URL may fit better in this case (it lists all connector properties).

Comment: version 5.1.16 of the jdbc software contains this bugfix:   - Fix for BUG#57808 - wasNull not set for DATE field with value 0000-00-00 in getDate() although zeroDateTimeBehavior is convertToNull.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for the info. I guess you had a hard time figuring that out :-(

Answer (score 11):

> My point is that I just want the raw DATETIME string, so I can parse it myself as is.

That makes me think that your "workaround" is not a workaround, but in fact the only way to get the value from the database into your code:

```
SELECT CAST(add_date AS CHAR) as add_date
```

By the way, some more notes from the MySQL documentation:

MySQL [Constraints on Invalid Data](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/constraint-invalid-data.html):

> Before MySQL 5.0.2, MySQL is forgiving of illegal or improper data values and coerces them to legal values for data entry. In MySQL 5.0.2 and up, that remains the default behavior, but you can change the server SQL mode to select more traditional treatment of bad values such that the server rejects them and aborts the statement in which they occur.
>
> [..]
>
> If you try to store NULL into a column that doesn't take NULL values, an error occurs for single-row INSERT statements. For multiple-row INSERT statements or for INSERT INTO ... SELECT statements, MySQL Server stores the implicit default value for the column data type.

MySQL 5.x [Date and Time Types](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-types.html):

> MySQL also allows you to store '0000-00-00' as a “dummy date” (if you are not using the NO_ZERO_DATE SQL mode). This is in some cases more convenient (and uses less data and index space) than using NULL values.
>
> [..]
>
> By default, when MySQL encounters a value for a date or time type that is out of range or otherwise illegal for the type (as described at the beginning of this section), it converts the value to the “zero” value for that type.

Answer (score 6):

```
DATE_FORMAT(column name, '%Y-%m-%d %T') as dtime
```

Use this to avoid the error. It return the date in string format and then you can get it as a string.

```
resultset.getString("dtime");
```

This actually does NOT work.  Even though you call getString. Internally mysql still tries to convert it to  date first.

> at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getDateFromString(ResultSetImpl.java:2270)
>
> ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar:na] at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getStringInternal(ResultSetImpl.java:5743)
>
> ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar:na] at com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.getString(ResultSetImpl.java:5576)
>
> ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.15.jar:na]

Comment: That's kinda the same as my CAST(add_date AS CHAR) solution, but +1 since this lets you format it explicitly the way you want.

Answer (score 5):

If, after adding lines:

```
<property
name="hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</property>

hibernate.connection.zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull

<connection-property
name="zeroDateTimeBehavior">convertToNull</connection-property>
```

continues to be an error:

```
Illegal DATETIME, DATE, or TIMESTAMP values are converted to the “zero” value of the appropriate type ('0000-00-00 00:00:00' or '0000-00-00').
```

find lines:

```
1) resultSet.getTime("time"); // time = 00:00:00
2) resultSet.getTimestamp("timestamp"); // timestamp = 00000000000000
3) resultSet.getDate("date"); // date = 0000-00-00 00:00:00
```

replace with the following lines, respectively:

```
1) Time.valueOf(resultSet.getString("time"));
2) Timestamp.valueOf(resultSet.getString("timestamp"));
3) Date.valueOf(resultSet.getString("date"));
```

Answer (score 5):

I wrestled with this problem and implemented the 'convertToNull' solutions discussed above. It worked in my local MySql instance. But when I deployed my Play/Scala app to Heroku it no longer would work. Heroku also concatenates several args to the DB URL that they provide users, and this solution, because of Heroku's use concatenation of "?" before their own set of args, will not work. However I found a different solution which seems to work equally well.

SET sql_mode = 'NO_ZERO_DATE';

I put this in my table descriptions and it solved the problem of '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp

Answer (score 3):

I suggest you use null to represent a null value.

What is the exception you get?

BTW:

There is no year called 0 or 0000. (Though some dates allow this year)

And there is no 0 month of the year or 0 day of the month. (Which may be the cause of your problem)

Comment: yes, but there is still no year called 0, even retrospectively.  The year before 1 AD/CE was 1 BC/BCE

Comment: That's the whole reason MySQL uses 0000 as an invalid date, because it doesn't conflict with existing dates. Also, dates like 1999-00-00 is sometimes used (not by me!) to represent the year 1999 rather than a specific day.

Answer (score 3):

I solved the problem considerating '00-00-....' isn't a valid date, then, I changed my SQL column definition adding "NULL" expresion to permit null values:

```
SELECT "-- Tabla item_pedido";
CREATE TABLE item_pedido (
    id INTEGER AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    id_pedido INTEGER,
    id_item_carta INTEGER,
    observacion VARCHAR(64),
    fecha_estimada TIMESTAMP,
    fecha_entrega TIMESTAMP NULL, // HERE IS!!.. NULL = DELIVERY DATE NOT SET YET
    CONSTRAINT fk_item_pedido_id_pedido FOREIGN KEY (id_pedido)
        REFERENCES pedido(id),...
```

Then, I've to be able to insert NULL values, that means "I didnt register that timestamp yet"...

```
SELECT "++ INSERT item_pedido";
INSERT INTO item_pedido VALUES
(01, 01, 01, 'Ninguna', ADDDATE(@HOY, INTERVAL 5 MINUTE), NULL),
(02, 01, 02, 'Ninguna', ADDDATE(@HOY, INTERVAL 3 MINUTE), NULL),...
```

The table look that:

```
mysql> select * from item_pedido;
+----+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
| id | id_pedido | id_item_carta | observacion | fecha_estimada      | fecha_entrega       |
+----+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
|  1 |         1 |             1 | Ninguna     | 2013-05-19 15:09:48 | NULL                |
|  2 |         1 |             2 | Ninguna     | 2013-05-19 15:07:48 | NULL                |
|  3 |         1 |             3 | Ninguna     | 2013-05-19 15:24:48 | NULL                |
|  4 |         1 |             6 | Ninguna     | 2013-05-19 15:06:48 | NULL                |
|  5 |         2 |             4 | Suave       | 2013-05-19 15:07:48 | 2013-05-19 15:09:48 |
|  6 |         2 |             5 | Seco        | 2013-05-19 15:07:48 | 2013-05-19 15:12:48 |
|  7 |         3 |             5 | Con Mayo    | 2013-05-19 14:54:48 | NULL                |
|  8 |         3 |             6 | Bilz        | 2013-05-19 14:57:48 | NULL                |
+----+-----------+---------------+-------------+---------------------+---------------------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Finally: JPA in action:

```
@Stateless
@LocalBean
public class PedidosServices {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="vagonpubPU")
    private EntityManager em;

    private Logger log = Logger.getLogger(PedidosServices.class.getName());

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public List<ItemPedido> obtenerPedidosRetrasados() {
        log.info("Obteniendo listado de pedidos retrasados");
        Query qry = em.createQuery("SELECT ip FROM ItemPedido ip, Pedido p WHERE" +
                " ip.fechaEntrega=NULL" +
                " AND ip.idPedido=p.id" +
                " AND ip.fechaEstimada < :arg3" +
                " AND (p.idTipoEstado=:arg0 OR p.idTipoEstado=:arg1 OR p.idTipoEstado=:arg2)");
        qry.setParameter("arg0", Tipo.ESTADO_BOUCHER_ESPERA_PAGO);
        qry.setParameter("arg1", Tipo.ESTADO_BOUCHER_EN_SERVICIO);
        qry.setParameter("arg2", Tipo.ESTADO_BOUCHER_RECIBIDO);
        qry.setParameter("arg3", new Date());

        return qry.getResultList();
    }
```

At last all its work. I hope that help you.

Comment: I don't think this addresses the problem of converting a MySQL DATETIME of all zeros into a valid date. It just shows how to enter null into a DATETIME field which is not really going to help much.

Answer (score 2):

To add to the other answers: If yout want the `0000-00-00` string, you can use `noDatetimeStringSync=true` (with the caveat of sacrificing timezone conversion).

The official MySQL bug: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=47108.

Also, for history, JDBC used to return `NULL` for `0000-00-00` dates but now return an exception by default.
[Source](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/mysql-error-java-sql-sqlexception.html)

Answer (score 1):

you can append the jdbc url with

```
?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8
```

With the help of this, sql convert '0000-00-00 00:00:00'  as null value.

eg:

```
jdbc:mysql:<host-name>/<db-name>?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull&autoReconnect=true&characterEncoding=UTF-8&characterSetResults=UTF-8
```