# ormlite: Dealing with a default Value of "0000-00-00" for a Date column in Mysql

Tags: java, mysql, ormlite

I have to use an existing Database that I can not change that uses this column definition:

```
"birthdate" date NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00'
```

The default value is not a valid date:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: Cannot convert value '0000-00-00' from column 29 to TIMESTAMP.

Is there a way to return `null` from ormlite if the default value `'0000-00-00'` is found?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782823/handling-datetime-values-0000-00-00-000000-in-jdbc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way you can do this is with a custom persister.  You can then control how [ORMLite](http://ormlite.com/) stores and retrieves data from the database.   This feature is [unfortunately] not well documented.

You specify the class like this:

```
@DatabaseField(persisterClass = MyDatePersister.class)
Date birthDate;
```

Then your persister class might look like:

```
public class MyDatePersister extends com.j256.ormlite.field.types.BaseDataType {
    private static final MyDatePersister singleTon = new MyDatePersister();
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    private static final Timestamp ZERO_TIMESTAMP = new Timestamp(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0);

    private MyDatePersister() {
        super(SqlType.DATE, new Class<?>[] { Date.class });
    }

    public static MyDatePersister getSingleton() {
        return singleTon;
    }

    @Override
    public Object resultToSqlArg(FieldType fieldType, DatabaseResults results,
            int columnPos) throws SQLException {
        Timestamp timestamp = results.getTimestamp(columnPos);
        if (timestamp == null || ZERO_TIMESTAMP.equals(timestamp)) {
            return null;
        } else {
            return timestamp;
        }
    }
}
```

[DateType source](https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/blob/master/src/main/java/com/j256/ormlite/field/types/BaseDateType.java) is online.  Hope this helps.

Comment: The exception already happens when getTimestamp(columnPos) is called - so im catching it there. Thanx for your help.

Answer (score 0):

How about changing your birthdate from a NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00' to allow NULL values then you do not have to handle the '0000-00-00' since from your information the birth date can be null.

Comment: I think the point is that s/he is working with an existing schema and data set.

Comment: @Gray Just trying to think outside the box, using the principle that a "simple" schema change would save her from writing more code which also needs to be tested, debugged and maintained

Comment: @ssmusoke - of course that would be the obvious choice. But a lot of systems and programming languages use those tables and I can not be sure about the side effects.

Answer (score 0):

There is another way to do this. For JDBC connection String add following: **zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull**.

So after adding this to connection string, it will look like as following: jdbc:mysql://:/?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull

hth,
Narendra