# Java+mySQL: Read Date as String

Tags: java, mysql, datetime

I try to read out a table and write it into a csv file.

```
while (rs2.next())
{
    Enumeration<String> en = sqlfields.keys();
    while (en.hasMoreElements())
    {
        String field = en.nextElement();
        String value = rs2.getString(field);
        bw.write(Kapseln + value + Kapseln + Trennzeichen);
    }

    bw.newLine();
    cur++;
}
```

But if the field is type: DateTime, I get this error message:

```
java.sql.SQLException: Cannot convert value 
'0000-00-00 00:00:00' from column 12 to TIMESTAMP.
```

Why Java tries to convert to a Timestamp?

I like to get the value as String => `rs2.getString(field)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782823/handling-datetime-values-0000-00-00-000000-in-jdbc

Answer (score 3, accepted):

set

```
zeroDateTimeBehavior="convertToNull"
```

in your JDBC connection properties. ref: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html

**EDIT** that would make your connection string look like this:

```
jdbc:mysql://yourserver:3306/yourdatabase?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

Comment: This is true only if he is using mysql. Probably he is, since mysql is emulating null times with '0000-00-00 00:00:00'.

Comment: I did not put the 'mysql' tag on the question.

Comment: @bpgergo:) mysql was tagged in the original post [see](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/12621716/edit/ae37f643-985b-4546-90ce-8148d8b66c2e).

Answer (score 0):

The following code is working fine. Check your code with this...
The fourth field of the emp table is jDate which is a DateTime data type.

```
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","test");

        System.out.println("Connection is : " + con);
        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
        ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("select * from emp");

        //stmt = con.createStatement();

        while(rs.next()) {
            String value = rs.getString(4);
            System.out.println(value);
        }
        System.out.println("Connection is : " + con);
        con.close();
```