# Cast empty date field using Korma and MySQL

Tags: clojure, korma

Using Korma and MySQL I am trying to select from a table named posts, there is a field for the published date that is nil by default.

```
mysql> describe posts;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default             | Extra |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | 0                   |       |
| title     | varchar(250) | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| content   | text         | YES  |     | NULL                |       |
| status    | tinyint(1)   | YES  |     | 0                   |       |
| created   | timestamp    | NO   |     | CURRENT_TIMESTAMP   |       |
| published | timestamp    | NO   |     | 0000-00-00 00:00:00 |       |
| author    | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL                |       |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------------------+-------+
7 rows in set (0.02 sec)
```

If I try to select and use the published field I get the following error:

> user=> (select posts (fields :id :title :content :status :created
>   :**published**)) Failure to execute query with SQL: SELECT posts.id,
>   posts.title, posts.content, posts.status, posts.created,
>   posts.published FROM posts  ::  [] ClassCastException
>   java.lang.RuntimeException cannot be cast to java.sql.SQLException 
>   clojure.java.jdbc/print-sql-exception (jdbc.clj:350)

If I don't use the published field everything works fine:

> user=> (select posts (fields :id :title :content :status :created 
>   :author)) [{:id 1, :title "Hello World!", :content "*Welcome to
>   Beats, the World's most advanced Clojure Beat Engine!*", :status
>   true, :created #, :author 1} {:id 2,
>   :title "Hello World!, again!", :content "Sayin 't 'gain! *Welcome
>   to Beats, the World's most advanced Clojure Beat Engine!*",
>   :status true, :created #, :author 2}]

How can I handle this field?  I've tried to add a transform function to my entity with just a simple log statement, but it doesn't appear to even get called.

Comment: actually, `published` is defined as `NOT NULL` (`NO` in the null column). if you don't provide a value, mysql will fill in the default 0000-00-00 timestamp

Comment: Actually Marc is right. Also you should try to resolve full stacktrace: (use 'clojure.stacktrace) (print-stack-trace *e)

Answer (score 2):

Assuming Marc B is right, and that the cause of the problem is that you have a record with published as 0000-00-00, then you can add zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull to your Korma mysql :db key, e.g:

```
:db "mydb?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull"
```

Now JDBC and thus Korma will return published nil for that record:

```
(select posts (fields :id :published))
;; [{:published nil, :id 1}]
```

You may have to restart your repl for the flag to take effect.

See also:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html
- [handling DATETIME values 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in JDBC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782823/handling-datetime-values-0000-00-00-000000-in-jdbc)