# How do I insert MySQL table's default datetime value in a column when using annotated JPA objects (Hibernate JPA provider)?

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, jpa

I have a MySQL database (legacy) that I am writing a JPA layer for. I'm using Hibernate as JPA provider and have mapped my database tables with annotated Java classes.

One column in the database contains timestamps and has a default value (all-zero, i.e. 0000-00-00 00:00:00, but the issue is the same regardless of whether this default is something else):

```
releasedate TIMESTAMP DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
```

This is annotated like so:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@Column(name = "releasedate", nullable = false, length = 19)
public Date getReleasedate() {
    return this.releasedate;
}
```

Typically I want the default value when creating new entries and so I do not set a date in my Java object before persisting it (it's null).

However, this results in the date being set to now, rather than the default value.

I could set the "insertable" annotation element to "false", but this is not desirable as there are times when I DO want to set a custom date on creation.

I've also tried providing a column definition in my annotation (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197045/setting-default-values-for-columns-in-jpa)), but to no avail.

I did have an issue with reading all-zero datetime values (as mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782823/handling-datetime-values-0000-00-00-000000-in-jdbc)) and solved this by setting the JDBC property "zeroDateTimeBehavior" to "convertToNull". This solved the issue for reading, but the issue remains for writing.

Does anyone have any ideas about what to do in this situation?

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

Usually null-values will trigger the database to use the default timestamp for the field.

I am not sure what if your session is stateless, the entity may keep the null-value in the java-field.