# Hibernate Criteria for Time > 0

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am to fix an older project, in which there is a database query gone wrong. In the Table, there is a field

```
viewTime TIME NOT NULL DEFAULT 0
```

I need to filter out the rows that actually have 0 as their `viewTime`:

```
Criteria query = /* create criteria */;
query.add(Restrictions.gt("viewTime", 0));
```

However, since `viewTime` is defined as a Date:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIME)
private Date viewTime;
```

I get a casting exception. On the other hand, I have no idea how to create a valid Date object that represents time `0`. I can't change the type of the field as well for this.

Any way I can express `viewTime > 0` in this `Criteria` object?

Comment: What actually exception? Can you provide stacktrace?

Comment: It's just an exception that an `Integer` can't be cast to a `Date`.

Comment: @LambdaDuck in this case try my solution posted below

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to compare date object with (00/00/00) but the any API will not produce DATE value like it.

This might your solution convert to null refer this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782823/handling-datetime-values-0000-00-00-000000-in-jdbc)

Comment: Though this solves it only from DB to Java, not the other direction.

Comment: @LambdaDusk I know but here when you do `new Date(0)` then it will return some date value not 0. it does not give error.but Is this equal to zero value?

Comment: Well you're right, but `null` doesn't either. I wish I could just see the generated SQL.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me, that you can try such construction:

```
Criteria query = /* create criteria */;
query.add(Restrictions.gt("viewTime", new Date(0)));
```