# How do I handle a null / 0000-00-00 00:00:00 DateTime in Java

Tags: java, datetime, null, nullpointerexception, type-conversion

So, I'm reading a database that contains values for date such as null or 0000-00-00 00:00:00. I read the values as a String, so it doesn't matter when I am reading them. However, the problem arises when I am inserting the values. I am using PreparedStatement for this:

```
preparedStatement.setTimestamp(9, new Timestamp(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").parse(tableRow.get(i).get(0)).getTime()));
```

Will the fact that I have those null date times cause any problems when I actually carry out this set action? Is there any way to possibly mollify this?

Comment: A null value, yes, a zeroed value no, so long as you don't mind it being zeroed.

Comment: possible duplicate of [handling DATETIME values 0000-00-00 00:00:00 in JDBC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782823/handling-datetime-values-0000-00-00-000000-in-jdbc)

Comment: This zero date is just made up to work for data bases.  There is no month 0, day 0 and there was no year 0 (although one has been defined in some standard) so you can't expect standard date time tools to accept such a date.

Comment: Null and `0000-00-00 00:00:00` are different