# util.JDBCExceptionReporter Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp

Tags: grails, jdbc, timestamp

i add two field to my domain Class ContentSequence : lastUpdated,dateCreated ,which is updated automatically by GORM.

After running the application again , i try to get a record  :

```
ContentSequence.get(1);
```

Unfortunately, i get the following in console of Web interface : 
org.springframework.dao.TransientDataAccessResourceException: Hibernate operation: could `not load an entity: [com.abdennour.content.ContentSequence#200]; SQL [select contentseq0_.id as id17_0_, contentseq0_.version as version17_0_, contentseq0_.chapter_id as chapter3_17_0_, contentseq0_.date_created as date4_17_0_, contentseq0_.difficulty as difficulty17_0_, contentseq0_.last_updated as last6_17_0_, contentseq0_.level_id as level7_17_0_, contentseq0_.name as name17_0_, contentseq0_.other as other17_0_, contentseq0_.owner_id as owner10_17_0_, contentseq0_.subject_id as subject11_17_0_, contentseq0_.type as type17_0_ from content_sequence contentseq0_ where contentseq0_.id=?]; Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp`

and in terminal , i get :

```
util.JDBCExceptionReporter Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do manually a queries SQL to update the value of Date field since Timestamp has minimum

```
UPDATE content_sequence
SET date_created = '2013-08-08 00:00:00';
    UPDATE content_sequence
SET last_updated = '2013-08-08 00:00:00';
```

and now, it is work.

Answer (score 3):

Error -> Cannot convert value ’0000-00-00 00:00:00′ from column XX to TIMESTAMP
Reason > 0000-00-00 00:00:00 is outside the range of a TIMESTAMP value (in fact, it won't work with a DATE field either).
Solution -> modify JDBC option 
jdbc:mysql://localhost/test?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull

Answer (score 0):

Also try `zeroDateTimeBehavior`

> - zeroDateTimeBehavior
>
> What should happen when the driver encounters DATETIME values that are composed entirely of zeros (used by MySQL to represent invalid dates)? Valid values are "EXCEPTION", "ROUND" and "CONVERT_TO_NULL".
>
> | Default Value | EXCEPTION |
> | --- | --- |
> | Since Version | 3.1.4 |

[connector-j/5.1](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-installing-upgrading-3-0-to-3-1.html)

[connector-j/8.0](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/8.0/en/connector-j-connp-props-datetime-types-processing.html#cj-conn-prop_zeroDateTimeBehavior)

[handling-datetime-values-0000-00-00-000000-in-jdbc](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782823/handling-datetime-values-0000-00-00-000000-in-jdbc)

[MySQL Error, "java.sql.SQLException: Value ''0000-00-00'' can not be represented as java.sql.Date"](https://helpx.adobe.com/coldfusion/kb/mysql-error-java-sql-sqlexception.html)

[MySQL: Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp](https://support.dbvis.com/support/solutions/articles/1000196182-mysql-value-0000-00-00-can-not-be-represented-as-java-sql-timestamp)