# Getting exception '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date Even if i am using resultset.getString() method

Tags: java, mysql, sql

I have a database table whose structure is as follows:

[image]

To retrieve the data i have used query `Select * from mytable`

In java I am using `resultset rs`

My code is

```
if(rs.next())
{
    str[0] = rs.getString("id").trim();
    str[1] = rs.getString("userid").trim();
    str[2] = rs.getString("keyword").trim();
    str[3] = rs.getString("field").trim();
    str[4] = rs.getString("type").trim();
    str[5] = rs.getString("assignee").trim();
    str[6] = rs.getString("category").trim();
    str[7] = rs.getString("subcategory").trim();
    str[8] = rs.getString("publicationDateFrom").trim();
    str[9] = rs.getString("publicationDateTo").trim();
    str[10] = rs.getString("date").trim();
    str[11] = rs.getString("time").trim();
    str[12] = rs.getString("assigneeNames").trim();
    str[13] = rs.getString("categoryNames").trim();
    str[14] = rs.getString("subcategoryNames").trim();              
}
```

The problem is i am always getting exception of

```
Value '0000-00-00' can not be represented as java.sql.Date[Ljava.lang.StackTraceElement;@42c7d3
```

Please point me in right direction.

Comment: Have you tried using getDate?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/782823/handling-datetime-values-0000-00-00-000000-in-jdbc  - Why not just make the date columns nullable?

Comment: @TimB yes, same exception.

Comment: @all Is it implicitly converting to date even if i am using getString

Answer (score 3):

you need add `zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull` to your mysql connection URI. Check [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) for more details

Comment: but its never null, and i am using getString method

Answer (score 0):

Firstly do one thing ..
change column to nullable and use following code feching the date from resultset

```
str[10] = rs.getTimestamp("date").toString();
```

Comment: Yes making it nullable is other option, but is it possible to do in this way

Comment: try above code may be its work

Answer (score 0):

Start your mySql with-

```
--sql_mode="NO_ZERO_DATE" --sql_mode="STRICT_ALL_TABLES"
```

then get your date using `getString` and use `DateFormat` for parsing. Then get it in ResultSet.