# Retrieving Timestamp data from DB using Mysql

Tags: java, mysql

I have a Java MVC model.Which has timestamp as one of the DB value which is already inserted into DB.I have declared the data type as Timestamp in DB,Now the problem is If i try to retrieve it is showing null values & can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp

Statement :

```
pstmt = con.prepareStatement("SELECT timestamp, FROM nid where id=?");
pstmt.setDouble(1, nidev);
            rs = pstmt.executeQuery(); 
            if(rs.next())
            {  
                timeBean.setHbtimestamp(rs.getTimestamp("timestamp"));

            }
```

Bean Class:

```
private Timestamp hbtimestamp;

public Timestamp getHbtimestamp() {
    return hbtimestamp;
}
public void setHbtimestamp(Timestamp hbtimestamp) {
    this.hbtimestamp = hbtimestamp;
}
```

**MyDB value is successfully inserted :2015-05-14 15:45:57**

**output: Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as** **java.sql.Timestamp**

Comment: what is the type of `Hbtimestamp` post the code

Comment: As well first print the value of `rs.getTimestamp("timestamp")` before setting it.

Comment: The data type is timestamp

Comment: This is what  i am getting Value '0000-00-00 00:00:00' can not be represented as java.sql.Timestamp

Comment: Go to hibernate configuration file add attribute showsql true. Execute code again and it will print sql equivilaent query in conolse the same query execute in sql prompt and check the result.It looks like your query itself not returning anything.

Comment: I am not using hibernate its a simple MVC architecture without any Framework

Answer (score 1):

Set in your MySQL

```
zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull
```

Then empty time stamp values will be interpreted as NULLs

Well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782823/handling-datetime-values-0000-00-00-000000-in-jdbc)

Comment: Sorry i did not get ,Can you please help me

Comment: I did this one added into URL & it is converted to null

Comment: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/acc_dev_db?zeroDateTimeBehavior=convertToNull

Comment: No i am getting Null value,I want the timestamp in DB